# How to list available tests with python?

Tags: python, python-unittest, test-suite

How to just list all discovered tests?
I found this command:

```
python3.4 -m unittest discover -s .
```

But it's not exactly what I want, because the above command executes tests. I mean let's have a project with a lot of tests. Execution time is a few minutes. This force me to wait until tests are finished.

What I want is something like this (above command's output)

```
test_choice (test.TestSequenceFunctions) ... ok
test_sample (test.TestSequenceFunctions) ... ok
test_shuffle (test.TestSequenceFunctions) ... ok
```

or even better, something more like this (after editing above):

```
test.TestSequenceFunctions.test_choice
test.TestSequenceFunctions.test_sample
test.TestSequenceFunctions.test_shuffle
```

but without execution, only printing tests "paths" for copy&paste purpose.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Command line command `discover` is implemented using [`unittest.TestLoader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html?highlight=discover#unittest.TestLoader). Here's the somewhat elegant solution

```
import unittest

def print_suite(suite):
    if hasattr(suite, '__iter__'):
        for x in suite:
            print_suite(x)
    else:
        print(suite)

print_suite(unittest.defaultTestLoader.discover('.'))
```

Running example:

```
In [5]: print_suite(unittest.defaultTestLoader.discover('.'))
test_accounts (tests.TestAccounts)
test_counters (tests.TestAccounts)
# More of this ...
test_full (tests.TestImages)
```

This works because [`TestLoader.discover`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html?highlight=discover#unittest.TestLoader.discover)  returns `TestSuite` objects, that implement `__iter__` method and therefore are iterable.

Comment: I couldn't find email to @vaultah so i'm writing here. I've updated license and attribution. I hope you'll forgive my initial innocence :). I also want to thank BoltClock for calm explaining my mistakes.

Comment: where to put code from @vaultah solution? in unit tests folder __main__.py?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
from your_tests import TestSequenceFunctions
print('\n'.join([f.__name__ for f in dir(TestSequenceFunctions) if f.__name__.startswith('test_')]))
```

I'm not sure if there is an exposed method for this via `unittest.main`.